# Issue with Rails after RVM installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version, rvm

I had the Rails 3.2.9 installed before I did the following.

I installed RVM using the command 'curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby' referring [https://rvm.io/rvm/install/](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/.)

Then ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 were installed using command rvm install [x]' ([x] stands the version) and I set ruby 1.9.3 as default using the command 'rvm use 1.9.3 --default'. Earlier I was using '1.8.7' which was installed before installing RVM. Now when I type 'rails -v' in the command prompt I am getting the following error.

> /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in
>   `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [bundler-1.2.3,
>   rake-10.0.2, rubygems-bundler-1.1.0, rvm-1.11.3.5] (Gem::LoadError)
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in`to_spec'
>         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
>         from /usr/local/bin/rails:18

Please help me to resolve the same. Good responses will always be appreciated.

Comment: rvm use 1.9.3 --default will set the default ruby version for new shells. Check with rvm list.
Did you create a gemset or install rails to the global gemset? Check what gemset you are using with rvm gemset list.

Comment: have you tried installing the gems after rvm use?

Comment: @all: The gem is up-to date. The command 'rvm gemset list' shown as follows.

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p327
=> (default)
   global

Comment: I don't know why I have been down voted. Kindly furnish the reason so that I could make that better next time.

Comment: I mean have you installed rails gem after rvm use? try listing the local gems using gem list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Question itself it is known that the issue is with some of the gem dependencies. So after setting up RVM, I updated the gems and installed rails using gem command once again. Then restarted the terminal. Wow, It works!! 'rails -v' outputs Rails 3.2.9.

One more thing I want to tell you that if you are using bash, just execute the command '/bin/bash --login' before setting the default ruby version. Otherwise it will throw the error shown below.

'RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.'

Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 3):

since you are using rvm you need to install rails 3.2.9 before doing rails -v try this command

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.9
```

and then try rails -v

Comment: can you please paste the output of this command "rvm list gemsets"

Comment: can you tell the output of  "gem list" returned

Comment: *** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.9)
actionpack (3.2.9)
activemodel (3.2.9)
activerecord (3.2.9)
activeresource (3.2.9)
activesupport (3.2.9)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.2.3)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.4)
json (1.7.5)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.5.0)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.9)
railties (3.2.9)
rake (10.0.2)
rdoc (3.12)
sass (3.2.3)
many more...

Comment: sass-rails (3.2.5)
sprockets (2.2.2)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
uglifier (1.3.0)

Answer (score 2):

Try passing --default to set the default ruby version

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Comment: But passing the default option is only required when you open a new terminal. There is nothing to do with default option as per as you are on the same terminal after executing rvm use. Right?

Comment: Hey, I have no problems with ruby instead the issue is with Rails after installing RVM. Hope you will suggest a good solution.